# RoR using Devise - Encrypted Password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi pardon my ignorance but I'm new to RoR. My problem is that I'm trying to make my Devise gem work but when I fill out the information and click Sign-Up, I get this in return: "undefined method `encrypted_password=' for".

I've already tried rake db:migrate and also clearing the attributes in the User.rb model but still it doesn't work.

Please any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most likely means, that you are missing on migrations.
Are you sure, that you have setup devise right?

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

```
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise User
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I started the app again and it worked, thank you very much though.

Answer (score 0):

In the rails console run, this will tell you if the migration has run

```
User.new.respond_to?(:encrypted_password=)
```

This should return true, if not do

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset
```

Comment: I started the app again and it worked, thank you very much though.

Answer (score 0):

In the site railscasts.com you can watch:

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise
```

after that you understand where you make a mistake 
If you then get an error - write comments and we help

P.S. gem 'devise', '1.1.rc0'  => gem 'devise' in gemfile